# Redirect from external url to my reactJS application routes with post method and some data

Tags: reactjs, redirect, post

I have a react application.when the user wants to pay he will be redirected to another site to complete payment, once finished, he will be redirected once again to the react app with post request and form data, I get then this response: Cannot POST /callbackurl. He's expecting me to get the data from the server side.
Is there any solution or workaround to get the post data from the front ??
Thanks.